# how to change dynamically adding element text using id?

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding `<a></a>` element.

```html
<div id="divbindProjectlist" class="col-sm-3">
    <a class="list-group-item active left-menu-head">Projects List</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList"><span class="project-name">Project 1</span><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="0.34084661019770524"></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList"><span class="project-name">Project 2</span><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="0.6971764238216627"></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList"><span class="project-name">Project 3</span><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="0.29109692149538624"></a>
</div>
```

Using below jQuery,

```
if (json.idPartnerProject == "0") {
    $("#divbindProjectlist").append('<a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList" >' 
      + json.ProjectName + '<input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="' 
      + json.idPartnerProject + '" /></a>');
}
```

After I am trying to update the existing Project name with respect to `idPartnerProject` id.

```
if (obj.idPartnerProject == pro.idPartnerProject) {
 //pro.ProjectName
}
```

Here, How can I update the Project Name inside the respect `<a></a>` element ?

Comment: Use innerHTML property.

document.getElementById("id of atag").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function will change the link text

```
function changeAnchorText(t, i) {
    var n = $.map($("#divbindProjectlist a.projectList input[type='hidden']"), function(i) {
        return $(i).val() === t ? $(i).closest("a") : void 0
    })[0];
    if (n) {
        var d = $(n).find('input[type="hidden"].hidprojectId');
        $(n).text(i).append(d)
    }
}
```

First parameter will be hidden field value and second will be the text like
changeAnchorText("0.19537117542457416","SomeName")

Answer (score 1):

If you could wrap the project name in a span, like

```
$("#divbindProjectlist").append('<a href="#" class="list-group-item projectList" ><span class="project-name">' + json.ProjectName + '</span><input type="hidden" class="hidprojectId" value="' + json.idPartnerProject + '" /></a>');
```

Assuming there is only one anchor tag, you could do

```
if (obj.idPartnerProject == pro.idPartnerProject) {
  //pro.ProjectName
  $("#divbindProjectlist a:has(input[value='"+json.idPartnerProject +"']) .project-name").html(pro.ProjectName);      
}
```

If you have multiple `a` tags youll have to keep unique ID's or change the selector to pick the correct one.

Comment: After creating a list of projects, then trying to change one project name then changing the whole project name.

Comment: Read my full answer thats why I said If you have multiple a tags youll have to find a more specific selector like an ID or by href.

Comment: Excuse me! I have tried to set ID but same issue occurred so I just comment.

Comment: Have you tried `$("#divbindProjectlist a#id .project-name")`.

Comment: Yes I have tried $("#divbindProjectlist a#id .project-name") this same code. but not working.

Comment: Did you replace `#id` with the real ID?

Comment: I have tried like this:  $("#divbindProjectlist a'" + json.idPartnerProject + "'  .project-name").html(pro.ProjectName); Is it wrong ?

Comment: First of all check if that is the ID of the element by inspecting it. Then add `#` after the `a` in the selector before appending the ID.

Comment: Excuse me, error throwing : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #divbindProjectlist a#'0.24411457661748703' .project-name.

Comment: That is not a valid ID.can you post the HTML of the anchor tag after rendering

Comment: I have updated html code from above question. Please look up on it.

Comment: @AbhiJA So the only that is different with all the elements are the values of the inputs and that is not the ID of the a tag.